# Parse string to produce predicate

Tags: c#, parsing, expression

I need to parse a string and produce a predicate (or expression, I'm not bothered) where the string takes the form:

"> 30"

I'd rather not write my own and there's a few libraries that do stuff like this - I've tried FLEE and NCalc but they seem to require the string to take the form "a > 30" and provide the value of 'a' as a paramter.

Is there a library that would allow me write something like

```
Func<int, bool> predicate = parser.Parse("> 30");

bool a = predicate(10); // false
bool b = predicate(40); // true
```

I need operators like <, >, =, etc, and support for OR and AND. And it's not just numbers I'm working with, strings and Enums are in the mix too.

Comment: And what would that predicate be equivalent to? It'd be quite easy to write, too.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance I've added an example to question

Comment: I can write it, if you tell me what the symbols you need are, and if you need numbers with a decimal point or integers.

Comment: If your strings could be formed only like 'operator[space]value', why don't just parse them with regexes?

Comment: Also, how would you like us to deal with strings and enums? I don't think there's an 100% right answer to "10" < "8".

Answer (score 8):

You could look into using the Dynamic Linq Library ScottGu has blogged about.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/bb894665.aspx

if should let you do something like the following.

```
const string exp = "variable > 30";
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "variable");
var e = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p }, null, exp);


bool a = (bool)e.Compile().DynamicInvoke(20);
bool b = (bool)e.Compile().DynamicInvoke(40);
```

or

```
Func<int, bool> predicate = (Func<int, bool>)e.Compile();
bool a = predicate(20);
bool b = predicate(40);
```

Comment: sorry... fixed a typo in my example, because the results are LambdaExpressions. not sure if that's still useful to you.

Comment: @EoinCampbell I updated your answer. Feel free to revert it if you don't like.